# Trying to Select TimeTickets from Database for just the user that created them

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, webmatrix

I have a small project on the go where a user can log in, create a TimeTicket and then view the TimeTicket.

When I go to view TimeTickets I can see all TimeTickets in the database.

I only want the user to be able to see the TimeTickets that him/her created.

I was thinking a simple query should work such as:

**"SELECT * FROM M_TimeTickets WHERE EmployeeID = CurrentUserName";**

All my TimeTickets are stored in a M_TimeTickets table.

All my User Info is stored in my UserProfile table.

- In my UserProfile table I have 3 columns. (Email, UserId, EmployeeID).

I would like to Select all TimeTickets that are equal to EmployeeID.

Comment: Is this a webapplication? If so are you using asp.net?

Comment: yes.. started with webmartix startersite.cshtml

Comment: I dont know a whole lot about webmatrix but I think you can get the current user by doing: WebSecurity.CurrentUserId

Comment: yes you can. 
I am trying to "SELECT * FROM M_TimeTickets WHERE EmployeeID = Websecurity.CurrentUserId"; but it doesnt want to work.

was wondering wether I have to set a variable for my current user than "SELECT * FROM M_TimeTickets WHERE EmployeeID = variable";

Comment: Can you provide the method that is calling into sql please?

Comment: Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this line:

```
  var selectCommand = ("SELECT * FROM M_TimeTickets WHERE EmployeeID = {0}", WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

To this:

```
var selectCommand = string.Format("SELECT * FROM M_TimeTickets WHERE EmployeeID = '{0}'", WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

Comment: That was Perfect. Thank you so much for your time. I have a feeling I am going to be back.

How do I set this question to answered.?

Comment: Yourwelcome, should be a check mark to the left. Just click that.